# How do I add new Textviews each time a button is pressed?

Tags: android

I am very new to Android coding and I have a question about creating textviews dynamically when a button is pressed.

I have figured out how to add textviews to another activity when a button is pressed but I want to make it so every time the button is pressed I want to add new textviews each time, not delete the old one created before.

```
      RelativeLayout Mainlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_job_tracking);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params6 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Intent aa = getIntent();

        String a = aa.getStringExtra("NAME");
        String f = aa.getStringExtra("ADDRESS");
        String b = aa.getStringExtra("EMAIL");
        String c = aa.getStringExtra("PHONE");
        String d = aa.getStringExtra("MOBILE");
        String e = aa.getStringExtra("QUOTEDESCRIPTION");
        String g = aa.getStringExtra("JOBDESCRIPTION");
        TextView NAME = new TextView(this);
        NAME.setId(vvv);

        TextView ADDRESS  = new TextView(this);
        ADDRESS.setId(vvv + 1);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, NAME.getId());
        ADDRESS.setLayoutParams(params1);

        TextView EMAIL = new TextView(this);
        EMAIL.setId(vvv + 2);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.vvv + 1);
        EMAIL.setLayoutParams(params2);

        TextView PHONE = new TextView(this);
        PHONE.setId(vvv + 3);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.vvv + 2);
        PHONE.setLayoutParams(params3);

        TextView MOBILE = new TextView(this);
        MOBILE.setId(vvv + 4);
        params4.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.vvv + 3);
        MOBILE.setLayoutParams(params4);

        TextView QUOTEDESCRIPTION = new TextView(this);
        QUOTEDESCRIPTION.setId(vvv + 5);
        params5.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.vvv + 4);
        QUOTEDESCRIPTION.setLayoutParams(params5);

        TextView JOBDESCRIPTION  = new TextView(this);
        JOBDESCRIPTION.setId(vvv + 6);
        params6.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.vvv + 5);
        JOBDESCRIPTION.setLayoutParams(params6);

        NAME.setText("Client name " + a);
        ADDRESS.setText("Client address "+ f);
        EMAIL.setText("Client email "+ b);
        PHONE.setText("Client phone number "+ c);
        MOBILE.setText("Client mobile "+ d);
        QUOTEDESCRIPTION.setText("Quote description " + e);
        JOBDESCRIPTION.setText("Job Description "+ g);
        Mainlayout.addView(NAME);
        Mainlayout.addView(ADDRESS, params1);
        Mainlayout.addView(EMAIL, params2);
        Mainlayout.addView(PHONE, params3);
        Mainlayout.addView(MOBILE, params4);
        Mainlayout.addView(QUOTEDESCRIPTION, params5);
        Mainlayout.addView(JOBDESCRIPTION, params6);
        Font application = (Font) getApplication();
        application.setTypeface(NAME);
        application.setTypeface(ADDRESS);
        application.setTypeface(EMAIL);
        application.setTypeface(PHONE);
        application.setTypeface(MOBILE);
        application.setTypeface(QUOTEDESCRIPTION);
        application.setTypeface(JOBDESCRIPTION);

    }
```

^^^This part is where the strings are received, params are set and a custom typeface is applied to the new textviews.

```
    final EditText NAME = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText ADDRESS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    final EditText EMAIL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText PHONE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final EditText MOBILE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final EditText QDESCRIPTION = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText JDESCRIPTION = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    final Button Donebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Font application = (Font) getApplication();
    application.setTypeface(NAME);
    application.setTypeface(ADDRESS);
    application.setTypeface(EMAIL);
    application.setTypeface(PHONE);
    application.setTypeface(MOBILE);
    application.setTypeface(QDESCRIPTION);
    application.setTypeface(JDESCRIPTION);
     Donebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final Intent aa = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  JobTrackingActivity.class);
            aa.putExtra("NAME", NAME.getText().toString());
            aa.putExtra("ADDRESS", ADDRESS.getText().toString());
            aa.putExtra("EMAIL", EMAIL.getText().toString());
            aa.putExtra("PHONE", PHONE.getText().toString());
            aa.putExtra("MOBILE", MOBILE.getText().toString());
            aa.putExtra("QUOTEDESCRIPTION", QDESCRIPTION.getText().toString());
            aa.putExtra("JOBDESCRIPTION", JDESCRIPTION.getText().toString());
            startActivity(aa);
        }
    });
}
```

^^^This is the part where the strings are sent.

Comment: you might want to consider adding a textview into a recyclerView. such that every time a button is pressed, a new card is appended. (this allows for scrolling behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("New text");
```

}

private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
    }
};
```

}

```
private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
final LayoutParams lparams = new  
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
textView.setText("New text: " + text);
return textView;
```

}

add this in xml

```
<LinearLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
 <Button 
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add+"
/>
```